# CodeIgniter not letting me log out?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, tankauth

Please Note I have fixed my Own Issue

Hi I am using CodeIgniter I have enabled sessions working fine in database but when click on log-out it goes to log out page bur shows errors. How do I fix it. I am using tank auth.

Example errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: session_id ,ip_address, user_agent, last_activity
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cws01/public_html/*****/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 675

Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cws01/public_html/****/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 542
```

---

```
<-- User.php -->

/**
* Logout user
*
* @return void
*/
function logout()
{
$this->tank_auth->logout();
$this->_show_message($this->lang->line('auth_message_logged_out'));
redirect('user/login');
}

<-- Config.php -->

$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

<-- Header View.php -->

<?php if($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()): ?>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <?php echo  $this->tank_auth->get_username() ?><b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><?php echo anchor('user/settings', 'settings') ?></li>
<li><?php echo anchor('user/logout', 'log out'); ?></li>
</ul>
</li>
<?php else: ?>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign in <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px;min-width: 250px;">
<li>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<form class="" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo base_url('user/login');?>" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="login">Email</label>
<input id="login" class="form-control" type="text" size="30" maxlength="80" placeholder="Email Or Username" value="" name="login">
</div>
<div class="form-group errors">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" size="30" placeholder="Password" value="" name="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group errors">
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="remember">
<input id="remember" type="checkbox" value="1" name="remember">
Remember me
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="login-links">
<a href="<?php echo base_url('account/user/forgot_password');?>" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Forgot Password</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('account/user/register');?>" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>    
</div>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Sign In" role="button">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><?php echo anchor('user/register', 'Register'); ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Please Note I have fixed my Own Issue

Comment: Instead of simply saying you've fixed it, could you post an answer below, so that this question+answer might be useful for someone else who is searching? Or if you think it's not useful, delete it.

Comment: Don't really know what I did just I just moved around some files I am self teaching my self. I have put tank auth in to hmvc format $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE; I think I had this set as true seem to work after refreshed page

Comment: in autoload.php file search $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session'), insert session keyword in array. If you solved issued or not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try this in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```